# Collision update is one physics update late, and it caused object to cancel its velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a character, he can move and jump. I need to check if it is grounded, so I made a trigger box collider as a characters component, and I use OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit to check if it is grounded, but the exit of collision with object that the character is standing on is detected one physics update late, and when it is detected, the upward velocity appears to become 0, and the character starts falling. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 4.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    private bool doJump = false;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    bool isGrounded = false;
    private float x, z;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Jump());
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            //this is movement
            rb.velocity = (transform.right * x) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + (transform.forward * z) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        }
        if (isGrounded && doJump)
        {
            doJump = false;
            rb.AddForce(0, jumpSpeed, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Jump()
    {
        //need the coroutine to make the player jump even if space pressed a bit earlier than
        //the character landed
        doJump = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.15f);
        doJump = false;
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other != this.gameObject)
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other != this.gameObject)
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to not use coroutine for jumping but it doesn't help. What helps is deleting the movement line.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement `"Pre_Update"` function, I have found this solution maybe you can use it:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/614343/how-to-implement-preupdate-function.html

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I think if you initialize your physics component in the Start function instead of the Awake function then it might work.